# How to solve createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: reactjs, api, post, axios

This is my code

```js
const onSubmit = (data) => {
  axios.post('https://lit-lowlands-70936.herokuapp.com/funds', data).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.data.insertedId) {
      alert('added successfully');
      reset();
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use .catch() after .then()

example:

```
axios.post('https://lit-lowlands-70936.herokuapp.com/funds', data)
.then(res => {})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

more: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors